# Encountered error when searching for user profiles on Manage User Profiles page on Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, userprofilemanager

I was searching for imported user profiles on Manage User Profiles page on Central Administration.

The search is **working fine for all other search terms** except **when I input alphabet "s" or "i"**. I then got an error page: "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred."

The ULS error log shows:

> 03/25/2021 16:05:44.47    w3wp.exe (0x180C)   0x1EF4  SharePoint
> Foundation    General 8nca    Medium  Application error when access
> /_layouts/15/ProfMngr.aspx,
> Error=UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
> UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID has null proxy   at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext
> serviceContext)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteContext..ctor(SPServiceContext
> serviceContext)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteContext.get_Current()     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs
> e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
> includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 7da9b79f-9b16-b0d5-f6fd-d8de4d91cfe4
>
> 03/25/2021 16:05:44.47    w3wp.exe (0x180C)   0x1EF4  SharePoint
> Foundation    Runtime tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
> UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
> UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID has null proxy    at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext
> serviceContext)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteContext..ctor(SPServiceContext
> serviceContext)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteContext.get_Current()     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs
> e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
> includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 7da9b79f-9b16-b0d5-f6fd-d8de4d91cfe4

I've been searching on the web for a long time but could not find out what was happening. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Verify your user account has Full Control in the Administrators and Permissions tab when highlighting the User Profile Service App in the Manage Service Apps page in Central Admin.

Comment: Yup i do have full control. But still facing the same issue.